# React Multistep Form with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I do got a working Multi Step React form structured like this:

```
MultiStep1.js
MultiStep2.js
MultiStep3.js
MultiStepForm.js
MultiStepSubmit.js
```

[See this Codesandbox for more!](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multistep-material-ui-iuyqcv?file=/src/components/MultiStep1.js)

In addition I want to add [Material ui](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/) components for a better design. At this point I am not able to pass/update props (data.age) to the Material ui Component.

```
  <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 130 }}>
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
      id="demo-simple-select"
      value={data.age}
      label="Age"
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

The selected menu item is in fact caught, even if it is not visible (why?) but is added to the `formData` as `undefined` instead of updating the age value. **How can I make the Material ui Component update the age value?**

**And why is the `MenuItems` NOT visible when selected?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this instead?:

```
const Step1 = (props) => {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const { data, handleChange, next } = props;
  console.log(data);

  const selectionChangeHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setAge(event.target.value);
    data.age = event.target.value; 
    handleChange(event);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 130 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={selectionChangeHandler}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>

      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 130 }}>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={next}>
          Continue
        </Button>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
};
export default Step1;
```

You're using the `<Select>` as a controlled component, so I used your state value, and update the data object using that value instead. If you bind the `Select` control to data.age, then that dropdown value won't change when you change the dropdown, it will instead change when you change the value of `data.age`.

Comment: Thank you! how would use the `selectionChangeHandler` for multiple `Select` inputs?

Comment: @Fjott Can you use different `selectionChangeHandler`s for each of the different dropdowns?